# Problem spawning Passenger/Rails application on AWS Red Hat EL 7 with FIFO permission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, passenger

I am trying to deploy a Rails application using Passenger with Apache.  Apache is working, but Passenger cannot start due to the following error.  Apparently there is a file permisisons in the `/tmp` directory, but this is on an AWS RHEL 7 instance, which seems to be set up differently than "normal" RHEL 7 servers.

```
Cannot create FIFO file /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXX29k0aH/response/finish: Permission denied (errno=13)
     in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePrepare::createWorkDir()' (Prepare.h:125)
     in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePrepare& Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePrepare::execute()' (Prepare.h:558)
     in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::internalStartPreloader(Passenger::SpawningKit::Config&, Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakeSession&, const Passenger::Json::Value&)' (SmartSpawner.h:345)
     in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:310)
     in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions&)' (SmartSpawner.h:1281)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
```

I have the Rails application owned by a non-privileged account and I have no problems creating directories and files in the `/tmp` directory as that unprivileged account, so it appears something else is going on.  Nor do I find the `/tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXX29k0aH` directory, or even anything like it.

This is my first deployment using RHEL 7 on AWS and there appears to be a number of differences between Ubuntu which I have deployed successfully in the past and RHEL 7 on AWS, which I need to use due to organizational considerations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Looks much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

## setenforce 0

Then

## systemctl daemon-reload

## systemctl restart httpd

And this if it will help